# Code working in Developement build But not in shipping UE4

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

```
void UCreateNewWindow::CreateNewMap()
{
    FString ThePath = FPaths::ConvertRelativePathToFull(FPaths::RootDir());
    FString GameName = FApp::GetName();
    ThePath.Append(GameName);
    ThePath.Append(".exe");
    FString MapPath = "/Game/Maps/Scene";
    //ThePath.Append(MapPath);
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(-1, 12.f, FColor::White, ThePath);
//  TCHAR* path= ThePath.GetCharArray().GetData();
    FPlatformProcess::CreateProc(*ThePath, TEXT("/Game/Maps/Scene"), true, false, false, nullptr, 0, nullptr, nullptr);

}
```

I am calling this class in BP. It works in developement builds but not in shipping builds. Since its shipping build i cant even debug properly.
Any ideas??

Answer (score 1):

It's a shipping build so unreal disables all functions that are for testing purposes.

AddOnScreennDebugMessage() is considered for development and well debugging.

Consider creating formal widgets instead.

Comment: but  FPlatformProcess::CreateProc() should works but it doesnt

Comment: Ah sorry I don't have any experience in threading. This is a lot more interesting and complex issue than I thought with the print to screen not working. I'll upvote though because this seems like a worthy problem.